# Can I solve this integral problem?

Tags: definite-integrals

I want to know how can i solve this function.

$\int{(1-y^d)^n}dy$

Is it possible to solve it? If you know the method, please teach me.

Comment: Are $d$ and $n$ positive integers?

Comment: yes. those are positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $d$ and $n$ are positive integers, you can just use the binomial theorem to expand the integrand, and integrate term by term, since it's a polynomial in $y$. 
$$
(1 - u)^n 
= \sum_{i = 0}^n (1)^{n-i}{n \choose i} (-u)^i
= \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i} u^i
$$
In your case, $u = y^d$, so this becomes
$$
(1 - y^d)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i} (y^d)^i
 = \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i} y^{di}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\int (1 - y^d)^n ~dy 
&=  \int \left( \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i} y^{di} \right) ~dy\\
&=  \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i} \int y^{di}  ~dy \\
&=  \sum_{i = 0}^n (-1)^i {n \choose i} \frac{y^{di+1}}{di + 1}. 
\end{align}

Comment: $(1-u)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \dbinom{n}{i} u^n$ ?! Following that, $(1-u)^2 = 0$. You obviously made a typo in that $u^n$. (: Consequently, the result is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. TLC (too little coffee) :). Fixed now, I think.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer give me pleasure.